# iPhone fonts for Windows

Tags: iphone, windows, fonts

I would like to support the default fonts provided by iPhone on my Windows server. Some of the fonts exist by default but others, such as "Zapfino" and "MarkerFelt" are not.

The idea is to create PDF files on iPhone and render them on a Windows machine. Since there is no (known-to-me) way for embedding fonts in a PDF created using the iPhone SDK, I would like to install these fonts on my Windows machine.

Is there an iPhone font package I could use?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could just purchase the fonts you don't have and install them on your windows box.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone system fonts are stored in `/System/Fonts/Cache/`. You use `NSData` to read them or  copy them to another location using `NSFileManager`.

<sub>Keep in mind you may be breaking license agreements if you distribute them</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As John M says, you can purchase the required fonts. The official sources are these:

- Zapfino: http://www.linotype.com/1175/zapfino-family.html
- MarkerFelt: http://www.patsnyderartist.com/patsnyder_fonts.html